# Change translation handling in Spring

Tags: java, spring, configuration, internationalization, locale

Sorry if the code is not sufficient, I'm trying to figure out how to start implementing this.

Basic locale beans are set up in the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    interceptor.setParamName("language");
    registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
}
```

The default functionality from this  is to read translations from different `[language].properties` files, that I do know.

My question here is if I can change that within spring. So instead of reading translations through files I read them through my custom method/functionality.

I tried searching for a solution, but I didn't run into anything.

For example, say I have translations in some java class (purely out of example) and instead of reading files I want to read through that class, where the inner functionality would be something like:

```
return TranslationConstants.getMap(translationKey, locale);
```

The reason why I don't just use it like this everywhere is because I wouldn't like the code to be like this and so I can still use view renderers to nativelly print translations (ie. `#{value}` in thymeleaf)

Sorry if the question is confusing/misleading.
Pointers to other similar questions are also welcome, I just couldn't find anything.

Comment: Implement your own `MessageSource` wrapping the functionality you want.

Comment: @M.Deinum that actually helps a lot! Thank you!